# Access denied for user to database

Tags: mysql

I have a user 'adminuser' with the following privileges:

```
mysql> show grants for 'adminuser'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for adminuser@localhost                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'adminuser'@'localhost' |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I am trying to grant privileges to another user who was just created

```
mysql> grant delete, insert, update, select, create, index on simpledb.* to 'jobuser'@'localhost';
```

but I get an error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'adminuser'@'localhost' to database 'simpledb'
```

Why?

Comment: flush privileges; and try again ?

Comment: @RamachandranGA same problem